# Any great way to create and share a GUI with developers?

Tags: gui-design, team, share

Does anyone know a great tool to share a GUI with developers (online perhaps)?

I'm working on a SaaS-system on my PC (Nope, i can't change it for a mac - therefore extensions for Sketch isn't a possibility). The system i'm working on i getting quite complicated, and we're talking about a massive designupdate. For that, i'm in need of a tool that can help me build a GUI, so i don't have to create titles and descriptions, type values etc. in Photoshop (I'm currently working in Photoshop however - i'm looking into Adobe XD. Experiences anyone?)

So - what i'm hoping, is to find a tool where i can build a GUI instead of doing it manually in Photoshop, and have the ability to see and share CSS with my developers.

How are you guys sharing your graphics with your team?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://balsamiq.com/products/mockups/)? Comes with some very usefull limitations to the non trivial designer - developer communication.

Comment: It is nice to create in webflow.com and easy to share in proto.io

Comment: voting to close. Hasn't got anything to do UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We recently switched to [Sketch](https://www.sketchapp.com/) with the [Zeplin](https://zeplin.io/) sharing plugin.  Sketch is already a powerful tool for both wireframes and hi-fi comps.  Zeplin takes material from Sketch and makes it easily sharable between designers, developers, and stakeholders.

What's unfortunate about Sketch is that it's Mac only.  What's great about Zeplin is that it can also import from Adobe, so it's not (entirely) married to Sketch.

It has some quirks, but after years of using Illustrator, Photoshop, Keynote (haha) and even coding up css directly (lest intention be unclear from static images), this is the best workflow we've discovered.

Balsamiq, Axure, and FramerJS all offer competing solutions, each with varying degrees of connectedness and interactivity.

Comment: Thank you Nathan! Apparrently Zeplin made an extension for Windows and Photoshop, so I think that this will be the app I'm going to implement to the designproces.